# SQLite Select next date time in future

Tags: sqlite, date, time

Hi I have date time entries like

1. 2022-09-16 12:31:27
2. 2022-09-16 13:31:27
3. 2022-09-16 14:31:27
4. 2022-09-16 15:31:27

Where the current time is I want to select the next entry in the future. ie if the current time is `2022-09-16 14:20:04` I want to select 3.

I think I need the `NOW` command but I'm not sure and it is not working.

```sql
SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY date(NOW) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You need a `WHERE` to limit the results to those greater than the current date. Then order by the column and the limit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want a query such as:-

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE date > datetime('now') ORDER BY date LIMIT 1;
```